# Image of subspace under the matrix linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ whose matrix in relation to the canonical base is:

$[T] = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -1 \\
        0 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

What is the equation of the plane which is the image, through transformation $T$, of the subspace $x + y + 2z = 0$ of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

The solution is $4x + 7y + 9z = 0$. Can someone explain how to solve this?

Comment: First note that your transformation is an isomorphism (I think it is). You can see this by taking its determinant for example. Then, take any basis of your subspace, since isomorphisms take bases to bases, see where are the two vectors of your basis sent to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=(x+2y-z,2y+3z,x-y+z)$.

$x=-y-2z, (-y-2z,y,z)=y(-1,1,0)+z(-2,0,1)$, $(-1,-1,0), (-2,0,1)$ is the basis.

$f(-2,0,1)=(-3,3,-1)$. You have $4(-3)+7(3)+9(-1)=-12+21-9=0$.

$f(-1,1,0)=(1,2,-2)$ $4(1)+7(2)+9(-2)=4+14-18=0$.

This shows that $f(-2,0,1)$ and $f(-1,1,0)$ are in $4x+7y+9z=0$ since they generates $x+y+2z=0$ it implies that $f(x+2y+z=0)\subset 4x+7y+9z=0$. Now   show that $f(-2,0,1)$ and $f(-1,1,0)$  are linearly independent thus generate this plane.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative method, though it is perhaps a little longer:

First, find a basis of your subspace. As your subspace is a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$, we know it will have dimension 2, so we need to find two linearly independent vectors which satisfy $x+y+2z = 0$. Through experimentation, I found that:
$$<1,1,-1>,<2,4,-3>$$

is a basis of the subspace, because each vector satisfies the desired equation and the two vectors are linearly independent (though, perhaps you could find a different basis that is easier to work with).

We next apply the linear transformation to the basis vectors to find the image of the subspace. I receive:

$$<4, -1, -1>, <13,-1,-5>$$

Which we note are two linearly independent vectors, and thus they will span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

We then can compute the cross product of these two vectors to find a vector orthogonal to them, and this will be the normal vector of the plane in the image, which we can use to write the equation of the plane.

A computation of the cross product produces the normal vector: $<4,7,9>$, and then the normal vector can be used to write the equation of the plane as:

$$4x+7y+9z=0$$

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could accept this as an answer as well. In the original question there are 5 alternatives of plane equations, so it is possible to just test the images of the subspace with each one until it equals to zero, like Tsemo showed in his answer. But I like your way as it generates the plane without the need for testing the alternatives. And even if I use the other basis <-1, 1, 0> and <-2, 0, 1> (which I would problably do), the cross product of their images still produces the vector <4, 7, 9>.

Comment: You don’t need to experiment to find a basis for the original plane. One can immediately write down a basis for it by noting that, written as a row vector, $(1,1,2)$ is a matrix in row-reduced echelon form.